# Max file size not updating

Tags: functions, uploads, php.ini

Hi I am a beginner at WordPress and am currently trying to increase my file upload size.

So far I've tried two ways:

The first way was to add this to the bottom of the functions.php file:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

That didn't seem to work.

The second way I tried was to install the PHP Settings plugin and add this to the file

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

However, when I try to verify that my change updated by clicking on `Media > Add New`, I still see 8MB as the max file size:

[image]

How would I do this? I'm trying to upload a theme that's 8MB+ and it won't work because of this limitation.

P.S. I'm using MAMP to start my server.

Comment: If you have access to the php.ini file on the server, you would set max_upload_size there (and restart the apache process). Otherwise, you should be able to create an *.htaccess* file in the root of your wordpress site, and add `php_value upload_max_filesize 30M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1] To do this, change the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size directives in your php.ini file.
To ensure that file uploads work correctly, the post_max_size directive should be a little larger than the upload_max_filesize. For example, the following settings demonstrate how to set a file upload limit to 20 megabytes:**

upload_max_filesize = 20M
   post_max_size = 21M

**2]  You need to add the following codes at the bottom of the .htaccess file:**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

**ref links:**  https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-maximum-upload-file-size/
            https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-maximum-upload-file-size/

Comment: Are you saying that you need to edit both the php.ini file **and** the .htaccess file? Yours is the only post I've seen which indicates you need to do both.