# File upload size limit in wordpress and php.ini limit

Tags: images

I am developing a wordpress site, I have hosted my wordpress site on **Infinityfree.com** as of now.

I am trying to upload a plugin which is **18MB** and landing with this error

> "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in
>   php.ini."

I have tried everything possible, that is i have altered config in **.htaccess**, i have always edited **wp-config.php** and also added **max_size** to **php.ini;** i have restarted my server too. But I am unable to resolve this error and upload a plugin above **10MB**.

Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: hi Rajath please check link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320700/max-file-size-not-updating/320722#320722

Answer (score 0):

I checked and it seems that your host infinityfree.net block custom php settings.
infinityfree.com doesn't exist.

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-can-i-protect-php-ini-with-suphp.127537/#post-554049

https://bobcares.com/blog/disable-custom-user-ini-easyapache-4/

Comment: yea, you are right. Thanks though!